# PHP page downloading instead of actually viewing the page

Tags: html, css

I am currently attempting to create my first website and I have ran into a problem with the .php page. I'm trying to create the contact form and for some reason when I submit, instead of viewing the page it downloads. I made sure that I had PHP7 downloaded to the latest version. (I am using Visual Studio Code if that helps). Here is the code.

Html:

```
        <div class="container-form">
        <form action="action_page.php">
            <label class="firstName" for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail..">

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn-send"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-send']))
{
    echo 'Working';
}
?>`
```

The PHP is very simple. Just checks if the page is working.

Comment: Try to add <form action="action_page.php" method="post"> in form

Comment: Sounds like you don't have php config on a webserver. Just downloading php doesn't mean its configured. Do you have a local webserver installed? Try downloading and setting up Mamp and then try again.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester Yes you are right. I didn't have a local web server. Thing is I have no clue how to use it. I'll learn how. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Download Mamp https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/ and follow instructions online there. You just need a folder where you have all your web files and mamp will do the rest.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester I've done everything accordingly and my php page actually opens. However, the code doesn't run. Instead, I can only see the code itself. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you haven’t switched php on in mamp. Check left Column in mamp to make sure it’s on or check in the host settings for the new site that you created in mamp

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case, then probably your server is not "parsing" (handling) the php file. Please check the configuration to make sure that the php files are handled by php "parser" (and not as usual html or other files).
What web server are you using ?

Comment: yes. The problem is me not using a web server. I'm not very familiar to how to host it .It's my first website. Sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry. This is very common issue when your php parser dies (for any reason). Still, it is kind of dangerous, as you might have some secret code which will be just delivered for download.
So, in a future, when you have passwords, hashes salts etc in your code, be more careful